# Access User Desktop Files While Using Root

Tags: ubuntu, desktop, root, user

I'm really new ubuntu user...

I'm working as *root* user (the software that I'm using just works if you are root user) but the files that I need to access are on my normal user desktop. I don't how to get to the desktop while I'm root.

Comment: Welcome Adenes. On simple question try always to check on your preferred search engine for a solution. If you write in google `where is  user  desktop folder in ubuntu` you find the solution. 
The `'` is preferred to `\`` because the latter is user to write little pieces of code... and to show it in your question you have to _escape it_ `\\``

Comment: Are you using command line based tools? If yes, look at the 'sudo' and/or 'su' command. Both allow you to obtain root privileges.

Answer (score 4):

The desktop for `user` will be located at `/home/user/Desktop`.

Answer (score 0):

Simple, try this:

```
cd /home/your_username/Desktop
```

There are your files, you can list them using `ls`

Answer (score 0):

In addition to above answers, if you need to use it frequently. Make a soft link to the desktop of the normal user.

```
root@your_host ~/Desktop]# ln -s /home/Adenes/Desktop
```

Above will create a shortcut in root's Desktop.